# Why Form needs ID in JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, xhtml

FORM is not visible in html.
I wonder why form has the ID to match the function.
What is it for?

[image]

Comment: Please don't include external links to pictures of your code, just paste the code into your question as text. Are those form IDs referenced in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you saying that the id attribute is mandatory in JSF? Or are you just wondering what the id can be used for? In that case, apart from assigning CSS, there is the `form` attribute in `input` elements...

Comment: The `h:form` tag doesn't need an assigned id attribute in JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute on `h:form` component is not mandatory.
If don't use it JSF will provide/generate one for you.